# Two-dimensional array error

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone fix my problem and tell me where I've failed?
I'm studying and I can´t get further on.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char *caract[][] = { {"Bandeira",1,10},
                         {"Superior",2,1,1},
                         {"Pele dura",3,2,2},
                         {"Armadura",4,2,3},
                         {"Faca",5,1,1},
                         {"Espada",6,2,2},
                         {"Agressao",7,1,1},
                         {"Ecologico",8,1,1},
                         {"HeatSeeker",9,1,1},
                         {"BuildSeeker",10,1,1},
                         {"walker",11,1,1},
                         {"Remedio",12,2,1},
                         {"SecondChance",13,3,0}  };
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<3; i++)
                printf("\n%c\n", caract[i][j]);
            j=0;
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) You haven't specified the error or which line is producing it, 2) We're not here to do your homework for you

Comment: You should read ['How to ask a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your error ? What do you want to do with this code ?

Comment: Why don't you compile it and run it with a debugger to see what happens and answer your own homework question?

Comment: it says:
error: array type has incomplete elemente type

Comment: And David, I've tried to do it and manage to fix it but i'm stuck, and i'me just studying, not homework

Answer (score 2):

This is not PHP or javascript, you cant just declare arrays with multiple types and expect the compiler to do the work for you. You must use structs to define what each element will be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct INeedToDoMyOwnHomework
{
    const char *string;
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
};

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    struct INeedToDoMyOwnHomework thingarray[] = { {"Bandeira",1,10},
                         {"Superior",2,1,1},
                         {"Pele dura",3,2,2},
                         {"Armadura",4,2,3},
                         {"Faca",5,1,1},
                         {"Espada",6,2,2},
                         {"Agressao",7,1,1},
                         {"Ecologico",8,1,1},
                         {"HeatSeeker",9,1,1},
                         {"BuildSeeker",10,1,1},
                         {"walker",11,1,1},
                         {"Remedio",12,2,1},
                         {"SecondChance",13,3,0} };
    for(i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", thingarray[i].string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems, both having to do with the declaration of `caract`.

First, you cannot leave both array dimensions empty; you must specify *at least* the outermost dimension(s):

```
char *caract[][N] = {...}; // inner dimension determined by number of elements in the initializer
```

Secondly, your initializer doesn't match up with the type of your `caract` array; you've declared it as a 2d array of `char *`, but your initializer is an array of records containing a `char *` plus three integer fields.

Answer (score 0):

Every single string should be in the `""`s. I think your code should be like this one:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char caract[13][20] = { "Bandeira",
                         "Superior",
                         "Pele dura",
                         "Armadura",
                         "Faca",
                         "Espada",
                         "Agressao",
                         "Ecologico",
                         "HeatSeeker",
                         "BuildSeeker",
                         "walker",
                         "Remedio",
                         "SecondChance"};
        for(i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<3; j++)
                printf("\n%c\n", caract[i][j]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Learn about 2-D arrays in C/C++ to know how they work from your book or somewhere else.

Comment: this answer does not implement the data in OPs posted code.

Comment: Didn't get it. Explain please.

Comment: the OPs question indicates 4 pieces of data in each entry, a char array pointer, plus 3 integers.  This answer only addresses the character array and skips the part about the entry should be a pointer to each char array.

Comment: Yes, I did this deliberately because he mentioned the problem as " Two-dimensional array error ". That's why I answered this way.